# Weird Characters shown just after booting from BIOS to Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, boot, bios

Just after booting from BIOS, Windows Vista should be in charge of the booting process, but the screen shows the following thing and halts.

[image]

Is reinstalling Windows the only solution for using Windows on this computer again?
I have tried LiveCD, it is ok.

Comment: This one I have no clue about!  except that your hardware is ok.  back up files with live cd.  if you suspect malware hose the drive down (zero it with dd from live cd) and save yourself some time.  rather than trying to clean the virus within the system thats been compromised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would reinstall the OS -and format the HD- to be on the safe side.

Live CD works because the OS runs entirely from the CD but the fact that you see that error when your computer boots from the HD is likely an indication that your file system is corrupt.